# Can AUC increase while both sensitivity and specificity decrease?

Tags: model-evaluation, auc, sensitivity-specificity

Assume I am given two classifiers - A and B. Is it possible that the specificity and sensitivity obtained from using B will be higher than A, but the AUC of A will be higher than the AUC of B?
Will you please give me an example?

Thank you!

Comment: The AUC does not depend on a chosen classification threshold, but specificity and the sensitivity do, so the question needs some clarification. Are you asking for some fixed classification threshold, is the above possible?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you!